# Should I use a dedicated circuit for a towel warmer?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I purchased a 120 volt (70 watt) towel warmer that will be hard wired into our bathroom. I have 12-2 wire on a 20AMP breaker already in there that will be used for outlets and lighting.

Should I run a dedicated line for the towel warmer or can I use what's already there?

This is the towel warmer I purchased: [24" KEEGAN HARDWIRED TOWEL WARMER](http://www.signaturehardware.com/24-keegan-wall-mount-hardwired-towel-warmer.html?trk_msg=SUH2TM2UGEE4J97T6637BBM0VO&trk_contact=39BRNPAGC8RQMS36NJ2OENEQ00&trk_module=tra&utm_source=Listrak&utm_medium=Email&utm_term=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.signaturehardware.com%2F24-keegan-wall-mount-hardwired-towel-warmer.html&utm_campaign=Transactional-Messages&utm_content=Order-Confirmation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [installation instructions](http://www.signaturehardware.com/media/pdf/925187-installation-instructions.pdf) there is no mention of a dedicated circuit.  As long as the additional 70 watts doesn't push your existing circuit over the 80% maximum (1920 @ 20 amps), go ahead and add it to the existing circuit.

Comment: I guess I should maybe check the wattage of all of my wife's hair tools like her hair dryer and flat iron :|

Comment: @bigmike7801 If anything, you'll want those receptacles uses for hair dryer, etc on a dedicated circuit and everything else on a separate one.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty small load, so it probably won't be an impediment, but you need to follow all the [rules for wiring in bathrooms](http://ecmweb.com/qampa/code-qa-120).

If the circuit powers hardwired loads only, this with the other loads can't exceed 80% of total capacity.

If the circuit powers hardwired loads and receptacles, the hardwired loads can't account for over 50% of capacity.

If the circuit powers receptacles *in the bathroom*, then it can only power things in that same bathroom.  NEC 210.11C3

Comment: I'm thinking it might be a smart idea for me to power all of the receptacles (somewhere between 5 and 8) plus the towel bar on one 20 amp circuit and then power the lights and 2 exhaust fans on one 15 amp circuit.

Comment: 8 receptacles is one hell of a bathroom.  Unless you mean receptacles in 3-4 bathrooms.

Comment: Nope. 8 receptacles in the master bathroom. My wife is a hair stylist and has a lot of hair "tools". She wants at least 3 receptacles above the counter (maybe more) and one in the top drawer of the vanity. Then there will be one in the water closet and 2 different walls will have them too.

Answer (score 1):

You should have at least one other circuit in that bathroom (considering 8 outlets) and use GFCI protection as well. 
"HAIR TOOLS" .. many of these are high wattage and therefore you will be sucking a lot of juice.

The towel bar is peanuts compared to the hair tools and other components.
Lights and Exhaust fans and Towel Warmer on a 20 AMP , 4 Outlets on a 20AMP GFCI, and 4 Other Outlets on a 20 AMP GFCI. Depending on placement of outlets - try to configure so the load will be balanced. Small price to pay for safe hookup.